# Error: Data supplied is of wrong type- IE localStorage

Tags: local-storage, internet-explorer-11

When trying to access localStorage in Console, I am getting the below error in IE 11. 
The Enable DOM Storage in Settings is already selected.

Error:
When I type localStorage in console, in IE11, I am getting,

```
Error: Data supplied is of wrong type.
```

In chrome, it is working fine.

Comment: does it do the same if you open the console on a simple test HTML page and type this, like a blank page? On a test one i get `[object Storage]{constructor: Storage {...}, length: 0, remainingSpace: 5242880}`

Comment: Same error for that also .. Error: Data supplied is of wrong type.